# Presenting Information on home page from another model? Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, twitter-bootstrap

I have a posts model... I am trying to display this model on the index page of the webpage.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= @posts[1].title %> 
<%end%>
```

The problem with the above code is that it display the title 3 times because i have 3 posts. How do i edit this code to make it only display once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant to do this:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %> 
<%end%>
```

The `each` enumerator passes its variables one at a time into a block with the `do |variable|` syntax. So `post` is each item in `@posts`, one after another.

This is a really fundamental concept to Ruby and Rails: without understanding this further you probably won't get very far. I would recommend you go and [read Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) -- a really excellent tutorial and reference to the Ruby programming language -- to understand how blocks and enumerators work.

Comment: I have been reading non-stop everywhere i go. Its hard to find when i know what i am looking for but know little. 

Regarding your answer, I am trying to display the FIRST title from posts, right now posts contains 3 "post" which all have a title,body,date. I am trying to learn how to display the first title, and then later in my code display the second title.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'each' it displays all the posts because in your controller you had @posts = Posts.all. This gives all the posts written till now into the @posts instance variable and each enumerator prints all the posts

If you want only the title to be displayed and that too only for the first post, then you can write like this in your view

```
<%= @posts.first.title %>
```